# Magento 2 Layout extend from blank theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am very confused by why magento is not executing the layout extension in my custom theme.

So first things first. I followed step by step the magento 2 documentation for creating a custom theme and I was able to choose on the admin the new theme as a default theme, so things were fine there. The parent of the theme is the Magento Blank Theme.

In order to make a small change - remove the sidebar from the catalog module-I extended the default layout from here:

```
 vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\default.xml
```

to here:

```
app\design\frontend\Company\theme1\Magento_Catalog\layout\default.xml
```

with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

but is not working. It only works if the default.xml is placed here:

```
vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Catalog\layout
```

So I know 1 thing by now, the default.xml extension file is working fine, the problem is that is not being called from the custom theme when is placed there.

Any suggestions ?